# How to parse the URL & check if that has https & display only the hostname in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, redirect

I have tried the solutions which are given for similar questions and tried some functions on my own too.
I have receiving the url from db so

```
const originalUrl = this.state.urlSource;
const newUrl = new URL (originalURl);
const shortenLink = newURl.hostname;
```

used that inside a tag

```
<a href={this.state.urlSource}>
{shortenLink}
</a>
```

this works but before refreshing the page after navigating,
its showing error like

> Unable to construct URL: Invalid URL

is that because of the https missing in the URL? if that's the reason, how can I check that but, I need to show the hyperlink string as hostname only but the redirect link will navigate to the expected url.

problem:

> https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

expected output:

> [www.stackoverflow.com](http://www.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: `const newUrl = new URL (originalURl); const shortenLink = newURl.hostname;` Javascript is case-sensitive.

Comment: I don’t think this question is specific to React. Rather, it’s to do with the JavaScript spec/implementations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Demo at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-noyce-ylovn?file=/src/App.tsx).

**Source:**

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [urlSource, setUrlSource] = useState("http://www.google.com");
  const [shortenLink, setShortenLink] = useState("");

  // This will trigger every time when you set new URL.
  useEffect(() => {
    const origin = new URL(urlSource).origin;
    const result = origin.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "");
    setShortenLink(result);
  }, [urlSource]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Get URL from DB
    setUrlSource("https://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask");
  }, []);

  return <a href={urlSource}>{shortenLink}</a>;
```

**Note:** Right click and then `Open link in new tab` to see it work.

Comment: If it was a class component, do I need to do it differently?
and thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You’re right that `URL` does require a protocol to be specified. [Any documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/URL) of the class includes a protocol in the examples, although I can’t  find anything specific that says it won’t work.

When I try constructing `URL` objects in Node, I get a clear `TypeError` when the protocol is missing.

Depending on your use case, like if you have some level of control over the URLs in question, could you assume the protocol to be HTTP(S) and just add it to the start of the URL string before passing it to the URL constructor? I know that it may not be possible in all situations.